# How to maintain multiple machines, multiple users for git revision control

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have n computers, and each computer has the same administer user name and password, but different computer name.

Now I have a project in gitlab server, it requires ssh key pair(computer and server). How do I pair all the computers with this project easily?

I tried to copy the isa_id.pub key to all other computers and add it to git project. But it doesn't work, because the isa_id.pub has the username@computer_name in the end, which of cause is different for different PC.

Thanks for any help!
Catherine

Comment: generate each user a pair keys. Then add each public key on the server.

Comment: Have you looked at http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to generate a new ssh key for each computer that will try to access your github account.

[This Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) on tutsplus is fairly easy to follow and explains it very well. It also explains how to switch between 2 different github accounts on the same machine.

Comment: The link is for multiple accounts management, not multiple PCs. right?

Comment: That's correct. However it also explains how to register a new computer. The multiple account part is an added bonus.